# Java Nested Queues

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

**Update:**

> In short, i have a queue which send messages from user to services.
>   But when one service get 1000s of messages, than queue is dominated by
>   it and other services are not getting messages until queue is empty. I need a solution to this
>   approach.

I have a problem for my BlockingQueue's. Lets say i have 100 external services which I'm responsible to deliver messages to them comes from users.

User -> Me -> 3rd Parties.

I'm using queue's in my App. Problem occures when one of the 3rd Party service is unavailable:

- Got messages from users to any of the 3rd parties. Save them in the same queue lets say Q1.
- Consume queue, identify the 3rd party service and send it to corresponding 3rd party.
- One of the 3rd party doesn't respond, timed out.
- Save messages that can't deliver them to DB.
- Regularly get non-delivered messages from DB and put them in my Q1.
- If that 3rd party gets lots of traffic, lets say 5000 messages, which fills my queue, than non of the other services get message from me until this queue is empty. But when this queue is empty, they will not get messages since i will get messages from DB again and put them in my queue, other services will be blocked again.

Solutiouns that i thought so far:

- Using nested queue by service id's, so i will identify blocked service 5000 messages at once and save them to DB without 5000 times consume messages from queue (may be more since messages will not be in order, they are all together with other services in one queue)

How efficient to use nested concurret queue (which i use BlockingQueue) or do you think better solutions to this scenario? Basically i don't want to let 3rd parties which are down dominate my queue. And i need a clever way to separate those queues, there may be thousands of them so creating a queue for each may be inefficent.

Comment: Have you considered using a reactive framework like RxJava?

Comment: You could mark those that get timed out somehow, and don't put them back in queue for an increasing amount of time. Say, first time you only put them back only after 5 seconds, second time they will be out for 10, then 20, 40, a minute, two minutes and so on. You get the idea. To not make your system idle, you can ignore the above if queue is empty.

Comment: I have to research RxJava first, thanks for suggestions. I have timeout map already which works like if X number of messages are timedout than new messages to service Y is written to DB instead of queue and will be blocked for Z times. After Z times if it is still blocked than new messages are blocked until Z+1 times etc. But on the other side this makes that service get lots of messages waiting in DB to process. When those messages are retrieved from DB to be processed, than my queues are blocked again.

Comment: Since it looks like you don't distinguish between different services, then it's perfectly fine to consider that all your system could be talking to for a while is some Service A, because that's what could also happen when no messages come in for other services natually for a while. I was, however, suggesting that messages get put on a bench for a time, not for  X messages that come in. Another thing which might help is to drain the queue of messages to service that has timed out, or to fill queue form DB in small chunks (100 or so) and never fill it completely.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using a single BlockingQueue that keeps messages for all third party services.

Instead,

- Use separate Blocking Queues and Queue Consumers for each 3rd Party Service
- When you get the message from the User, instead of adding it in the queue, identify the 3rd party service there itself and accordingly add the message in the 3rd Party Service Specific Blocking Queue.